# Modifying arguments of shell function?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm a bit confused on how to modify the function arguements:

I want:

```
bower ln
bower ln thing
```

to execute:

```
bower link
bower link thing
```

This is as close as I have gotten:

```
# ~/.bashrc
bower () {
    if [[ $1 == "ln" ]]; then
        ${@[1]}="link"
        echo "replacing" "$FUNCNAME" "$@"
    fi
    command "$FUNCNAME" "$@"   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `set` command:

```
bower () {
    if [[ $1 == ln ]]; then
        set -- link "${@:2}"
        echo "replacing $FUNCNAME $@"
    fi
    command "$FUNCNAME" "$@"
}
```

However, you don't really have to replace the first argument; you can simply hardcode the correct argument in the body of the `if` statement:

```
bower () {
    if [[ $1 == ln ]]; then
        echo "replacing $FUNCNAME $first $@"
        command "$FUNCNAME" link "${@:2}"
    else
        command "$FUNCNAME" "$@"
    fi
}
```